# How to convert the graph to list of all path using adjacency matrix via networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to use the networkx library from python to find all paths from my data set in the form of dataframe as I have attached the captured screen from what I have done.

[image]

according to the network graph, i would like to list all paths from this network then i have tried it with this code but it's not working.

```
from functools import partial
all_paths = partial(nx.all_simple_paths, graph)
all_paths
for x in partial(nx.all_simple_paths, graph):
    print(x)
```

the example of the expected result will be something like this

```
[[1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 5, 16]]
```

any suggestion?

Comment: And what you got out of your code?

Comment: i got the TypeError: 'functools.partial' object is not iterable

Comment: How about adding a **full** stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html), `all_simple_paths` find all paths between two given nodes, which are missing in your code. And I think you may misunderstand what `partial` does. From my understanding, `partial` repeats executing the function (1st argument) multiple times (2nd argument).

One way to find all paths in the network is to find all possible node pairs and then the paths connecting the pairs.

Example:

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

a = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0], 
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0 ,1, 0]
])
g = nx.from_numpy_array(a)

for x, y in combinations(g.nodes, 2):
    for p in nx.all_simple_paths(g, x, y):
        print(p)

# Output
# [0, 1]
# [0, 3, 2, 1]
# [0, 1, 2]
# [0, 3, 2]
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
# [0, 3]
# [1, 0, 3, 2]
# [1, 2]
# [1, 0, 3]
# [1, 2, 3]
# [2, 1, 0, 3]
# [2, 3]
# [4, 5]
```